# Existing content type add new/edit/display forms

Tags: 2013, content-type, form

I have a Content type that is being used on a list on many subsites.

I'd like to replace add/new/edit forms for that content type.

It is on Office 365 + i cant use sandbox code at all. Only option is to use Client Object model through silverlight or javascript's JSOM. I've seen an example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2008/09/13/define-custom-new-edit-display-forms-for-content-types.aspx) that deploys  new/edit/display forms path to '_layout' folder. Can i update existing Content Type to point to new forms on Office 365 that reside maybe on a sites root etc?

Answer (score 0):

Not in office 365. You can add your custom new/edit form as a custom action and let users choose that. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163954(v=office.15).aspx